# Merge text with stroke into a shape on Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm creating an SVG logo in Photoshop.

I have 2 layers:

1. Text layer
2. Shape layer

The text has a stroke. I need to subtract the text with the stroke from the shape.

Converting the text layer to a shape leaves the stroke out. It turns it into a shape with a stroke.

How can I merge the text with the stroke and turn it into a shape?

Comment: I do not believe you can with *Photoshop* if you want a *vector* shape.... You need a vector application - Illustrator, Inkscape, et. al. -- probably shouldn't' create "logos" in raster-based applications like Photoshop.

Comment: You can and I have created SVG icons with Photoshop in the past. You just need to use shapes to create the icon in order to properly export the file as SVG. I would use a vector application if I had one but I don't because I don't want to invest the money. And Photoshop was always enough for my needs anyways.

Comment: But you **can't** convert a layer style to a vector path. The *best* one could do is make a pixel selection, then convert the selection to a work path... which is often not very accurate. By "don't believe you can" I was referring to converting a layer style to a vector path/shape. I'm aware Photoshop can export vector SVG files.